# Help finding all points on a graph of the function $f(x)= 2 \sin(x) + \sin^2(x)$ at which the tangent line is horizontal?

Tags: calculus

I would appreciate help finding the answer to this question :]. Again the question is,

Find all the points on the graph of the function:

$f(x)= 2 \sin(x) + \sin^2(x)$

*the second trig function is supposed to be sin squared of x but not sure how to make that on here...*

at which the tangent line is horizontal.

Comment: You might find this useful if you're curious how to use math font on MSE: [MathJax Primer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! :]

Comment: The tangent is horizontal if and only if $f'(x)=$?

Comment: What I posted is the entire question...it doesn't ask/say anything else.

Comment: That's why we are asking you, what do you know about when the graph of a function is horizontal?

Answer (score 1):

We can calculate $$f'(x)=2\cos(x)+2\sin(x)\cos(x)=2\cos(x)(1+\sin(x)).$$ Now, the tangent is horizontal whenever $f'(x)=0$, so this means when $$2\cos(x)=0\quad\text{or}\quad1+\sin(x)=0.$$ Solving the cosine equation gives $x=\pi/2+k\pi$ for $k\in\Bbb Z$ while solving the sine equation gives $-\pi/2+2k\pi$. Since the solution for the sine equation is actually contained in the set of solutions for the cosine equation, we can write our final answer as $x=\pi/2+k\pi$ for $k\in\Bbb Z$.